# AsyncFileUpload hasfile gets value false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

`AsyncFileUpload.HasFile` gets null value on upload button click. Here is my code.

```
protected void ASF_personalDocs_UploadedComplete
    (object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    if (ASF_personalDocs.HasFile)
    {
        //upload file 
        string directoryPath = Server.MapPath("~\\uploads\\SharedDocs\\" + Session["username"].ToString().ToLower());

        string pathNameWithFile = directoryPath + "\\" + e.filename.ToLower();
    }
}

protected void btnUploadPD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string title = txtPDTitle.Text;
    labPDTitleErr.Text = "";

    if (title != "" && **ASF_personalDocs.HasFile**)
    {
        //code goes on
    }
```

}

after uploading a file with `AsyncFileUploader`, when I click upload button, value of `ASF_personalDocs.HasFile` is `false`.

Comment: Use Session for storing the uploaded info :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. What I found was that the Master page I was using had an UpdatePanel that housed the entire page, which includes the fileupload. If there is an updatepanel involved, your button is only causing a partial postback, which doesn't tell the server about the state of the asyncfileupload. Regardless of the reason, it seems like you're getting a partial postback. Registering the button as a postback trigger will resolve that issue:

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

`{
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnUploadPD);`

`}`